# AngularJS highlight filtered text in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list which displays properties from a JSON object. I'm displaying strings as well as numbers. I'm trying to highlight the searched input while the user types. I've seen many examples online but majority of them work work if you pass one single property from the JSON object instead of multiple.

```
<ul class="item-list" ng-class="{'scroll-list': overIndex.data.length > 5}">
                    <li ng-repeat="data in overIndex.data | filter:oiSearch ">

                        <span ng-bind-html="highlight(data, oiSearch)"></span>

                        <h4>{{data.marketing_name}}</h4>

                        <div class="item-container">
                            <div class="bar-container">
                                <div class="bar" style="width: 48%;"></div>
                                <span class="label">Enthusiasts</span>
                                <span class="value">{{data.enthu}}</span>
                            </div>



                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

HTML:

```
$scope.highlight = function(text, search) {
                if (!search) {
                    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
                }
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="highlightedText">$&</span>'));
            };
```

JS:

```
.highlightedText {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

CSS:

Comment: This doesn't feel like an appropriate use for `ng-bind-html`.  In general, you shouldn't use `$sce` to implement application logic; rather, you should use it to handle user created content.  In this case, a simple `ng-class` would be a better fit.

Comment: Only issue with that is I'd like to highlight what's typed to what it matches...If I type say "W" in the input box, I would like to see any string that contains that letter in the list or even numbers. Thanks though!

Comment: you can use a function to trigger `ng-class`;  it wouldn't be difficult to write a function that takes in your `oiSearch` and checks the item (each item in the `ng-repeat`), returning true or false to trigger the `ng-class` assignment.  Unfortunately I'm on a mobile device at the moment or I would try to write out an example, though I think there is an example that does something similar in the `ng-class` documentation...